# Do collocated grid arrangements definitely result in the checkerboard effect?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, finite-volume, discretization

I understand the checkerboard effect due to the use of collocated grid arrangements in FVM. However, I wanted to know whether this problem is definitely bound to effect the results? For instance, I have modelled some problems on 1D structured grids with a collocated arrangement and have produced smooth results. Perhaps I am mistaken in how exactly the results should be effected?

Comment: This depends on the problem. So unless you give more details about the equations you have in mind you will not get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I am interested to find out in general how does one decide whether or not to use collocated or staggered? Is it a trial and error procedure? For instance for the Euler equations governing a compressible flow at low mach numbers.

Comment: I would say the question collocated or staggered is one of stability. Usually staggering helps to fulfill stability requirements in incompressible flow where the pressure is a Lagrange multiplier and inf-sup estimates are crucial. In compressible Euler scenarios I guess this is not an issue and you only need to look for suitable fluxes and limiters. But I am no expert on Euler equations.